# umbraco tiny MCE 3 internet explorer insert link error

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce, umbraco

I have an instalation of Umbraco 4.0.2.1. In internet explorer (6 / 7) i get an error when trying to insert a link using the tiny MCE rich text editor. basicaly what happens is i can choose the node in the site i want to link to but when i click insert it reloads but the tiny MCE popup does not dissapear  and i get the following page error.

```
Line: 368
Char: 9
Error: 'the Form._SCROLLPOSITIONX.value' is null or not an object
code: 0
URL: "mydev server"/umbraco/plugins/tinymce3/insertLink.aspx
```

I dont get this problem in Firefox and i have other instalations of umbraco 4.0.2.1 in which this error does not occur. I have tried using WinMerge to comparing the code of the two instalations and they seem identical in all the places i can think would have an effect on tinyMCE ("bin", "umbraco_client\tinymce3", "umbraco\plugins\tinymce3")

I am pulling my hair out over this and any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but at first glimps I noticed the URL in the error message:

"mydev server"..

My guess: the javascript code cant handle the quotes in the url.

possible solution: **remove the space from your server name**.
again, its just a guess, hopefully will solve your problem.